# Libgdx - How to draw filled rectangle in the right place in scene2d?

Tags: drawing, game-engine, libgdx, shapes, rectangles

I am using scene2d. Here is my code:

```java
group.addActor(new Actor() {

    @Override
    public Actor hit(float arg0, float arg1) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(SpriteBatch batch, float arg1) {
        batch.end();
        shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.FilledRectangle);
        shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.RED);
        shapeRenderer.filledRect(0, 0, 300, 20);
        shapeRenderer.end();
        batch.begin();
    }
});
```

The problem is that it draws this rectangular relative to *screen* (x = 0, y = 0), but I need it to be drawn relative to my *group*. But if I draw other entities with:

```java
batch.draw(texture, 0, 0, width, height);
```

it correctly draws at (x = 0, y = 0) relative my group (0,0 pixels from left-bottom corner of the group).

Any suggestions how can I implement shape drawing in scene2d? And can someone can explain why these two calls work differently?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[ShapeRenderer](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ShapeRenderer.html) has its own transform matrix and projection matrix. These are separate to those in the [SpriteBatch](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.html) that the scene2d [Stage](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Stage.html) uses. If you update the ShapeRenderer's matrices to match those that scene2d is using when [Actor.draw()](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.html#draw%28com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch,%20float%29) is called then you should get the results that you want.

Comment: I had to do this myself recently - I set the ShapeRenderer's transform and projection matrices from the SpriteBatch which is passed into the draw() method. It doesn't seem very efficient but it works.

Answer (score 15):

As Rod Hyde mentions, ShapeRenderer has its own transform matrix and projection matrix.
So you would have to get the SpriteBatch's projection Matrix first.
I am not sure if there is an elegant way to do it, I did it like this:

```java
public class myActor extends Actor{

    private ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer;
    static private boolean projectionMatrixSet;

    public myActor(){
        shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
        projectionMatrixSet = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(SpriteBatch batch, float alpha){
        batch.end();
        if(!projectionMatrixSet){
            shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(batch.getProjectionMatrix());
        }
        shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
        shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.RED);
        shapeRenderer.rect(0, 0, 50, 50);
        shapeRenderer.end();
        batch.begin();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

The best solution for me. Cause when you using ShapeRenderer it's doesn't react on moving/zooming camera.

```java
public class Rectangle extends Actor {

    private Texture texture;

    public Rectangle(float x, float y, float width, float height, Color color) {
        createTexture((int)width, (int)height, color);
        setX(x);
        setY(y);
        setWidth(width);
        setHeight(height);
    }

    private void createTexture(int width, int height, Color color) {
        Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(width, height, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
        pixmap.setColor(color);
        pixmap.fillRectangle(0, 0, width, height);
        texture = new Texture(pixmap);
        pixmap.dispose();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        Color color = getColor();
        batch.setColor(color.r, color.g, color.b, color.a * parentAlpha);
        batch.draw(texture, getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to work really well: create a texture of the size you want, and draw that.  No messing about with shape renders.

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert the Actor's local coordinates into screen coordinates.  Assuming your stage is full-screen, you can just use [Actor.localToStageCoordinates](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.html#localToStageCoordinates(com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2)):

```java
vec.set(getX(), getY());
this.localToStageCoordinates(/* in/out */ vec);
shapeRenderer.filledRect(vec.x, vec.y, getWidth(), getHeight());
```

Where `vec` is a private `Vector2d` (you don't want to allocate a new one on each render call).

This is also assuming that your `ShapeRenderer` is defined to be map to the full screen (which is the default).

Also, if you switch away from the `ShapeRenderer` and back to the `SpriteBatch`, note that the `batch` is already adjusted to Actor coordinates (and thus you can use `getX()` and `getY()` directly with `batch.draw(...)`.

Comment: 1) Actor doesn't have .lovaltoStageCoordingates, only .toLocalCoordinates. 2) and I don't understand how to use it.. (ProgressBar is Group): `batch.end();
    vec.set(ProgressBar.this.x, ProgressBar.this.y);
    this.toLocalCoordinates(vec);
    shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.FilledRectangle);
    shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    shapeRenderer.filledRect(vec.x + 11, vec.y + 11, barMaxWidth, 20);
    shapeRenderer.end();`. I don't understand what I need to put to `vec.set()`.

Comment: How I understand from javadoc: "Transforms the specified point in the stage's coordinates to the actor's local coordinate system." for example I put x = 0; y = 0 for this rectangle in stage coord (it is left-bottom corner) And after I call .toLocalCoordinates() it should recalculate them and put in left-bottom Actor corner..

Comment: I set randomly for ex. vec.set(0, 800); and I got my progress bar bunch flipped horizontaly and when I scroll my pages those progress bars fly to another side. FYI: I have scene2d structure Stage -> Group -> Table -> Group -> Actor

Comment: You've got an older version of the Stage API, sorry didn't mean to send you off in a bad direction.  The older `.toLocalCoordinates` is the *opposite* of `localToStageCoordinates` (its for converting from stage/screen to the Actor).  You don't want to use it for rendering your Actor.  Probably best to use @RodHyde's approach with older versions of Libgdx (and perhaps with newer ones, too).

Answer (score 2):

If your are using the `ShapeRenderer` don't forget using `setProjectionMatrix()` and `setTransformMatrix()` methods...

A sample of draw circle inside an `Actor` on `draw` method :

```
@Override public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {

    batch.end();

    if (shapeRenderer == null) {
        shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
    }

    Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
    shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(batch.getProjectionMatrix());
    shapeRenderer.setTransformMatrix(batch.getTransformMatrix());
    shapeRenderer.setColor(mColor.r, mColor.g, mColor.b, mColor.a * parentAlpha);

    shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
    shapeRenderer.circle(getX() + getWidth()/2 , getY() + getHeight()/2 , Math.min(getWidth(),getHeight())/2 );
    shapeRenderer.end();
    Gdx.gl.glDisable(GL20.GL_BLEND);

    batch.begin();
}
```